# Bash glob pattern being expanded using remote data

Tags: bash, ubuntu, s3cmd

I have done this by mistake:

```
s3cmd del s3://mybucket/*
```

But ... *it is working*:

```
...
delete: 's3://mybucket/file0080.bin'
delete: 's3://mybucket/file0081.bin'
delete: 's3://mybucket/file0082.bin'
...
```

I am baffled. Usually `*` is expanded by the shell (`Bash`), using the information available in the `localhost`.

How/why is expansion working against an `s3` bucket?

(This is an unquoted glob pattern)

Comment: `scp` behaves much the same, applying globs remotely after invocation; you'll note that `scp host:*.txt .` also works (and indeed, works more reliably) as `scp 'host:*.txt' .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the glob doesn’t match anything it’ll remain as-is (unless you set the [`nullglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) option in Bash), with an asterisk in this case, and `s3cmd del` apparently understands that.

Of course it’s not a good idea to rely on this behaviour, since if a local file should suddenly exist that matches the glob it would (probably) stop working. Quoting the glob (i.e. making it *not* a glob) is a good habit.

An other option is to set the `nullglob` option (`shopt -s nullglob`) to make non-matching globs go away entirely.

To see how a glob expands and what the final command looks like you can run `set -x` in Bash before running it, which makes Bash print each (expanded) command before running it (`set +x` to turn it off).

Comment: So this *feature*  will work only whenever the pattern is not expanded locally. It very much depends on you not having anything matching the pattern locally then (which is somehow safe, since the pattern starts with `s3://mybucket/`). A bit brittle. Probably better to be safe and do `s3cmd del 's3://mybucket/*'`?

Comment: @dangonfast Yes and yes. I wouldn’t recommend relying on the glob not being expanded.

Comment: Could you add that suggestion to you answer? Good for me to accept.

Comment: BTW, `nullglob` isn't the only option that will modify this behavior -- consider `failglob`, causing the command to not execute (and `s3cmd` to not be invoked) in the zero-match case.